# Can't link CSS-file to JSP

Tags: java, css, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm building a dynamic web project using JSP and Servlets with Tomcat 7.0 in Eclipse. Everything works fine when I have the CSS-code inside the JSP-file, but when I'm moving it into a seperate file, I can't get the JSP-file to find the CSS-file. My file strucuture look like this:

```
MyProject
-src
-build
-lib
-WebContent
--MyJsp.jsp
--MyCss.css
--META-INF
--WEB-INF
```

This is what I've tried:

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "/MyCss.css"/>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "MyCss.css"/>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "/MyProject/WebContent/MyCss.css"/>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyCss.css"/>
```

Literally nothing works. The JSP-pages doesn't find the CSS-file. (I'm not using a web.xml and the first that is loaded is a servlet, if that has someting to do with it).

I know that other threads about this issue exists, but none of the answers works for me.

Hank

Comment: did you check the browser console what path it is looking for the css and what error it is giving. <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyCss.css"/> should work

Comment: What's the value of the 4th link in the browser?

Comment: Since the WebContent folder is the root of the site, the 2nd link as well as the 4th link should work.

Without a deployment descriptor (web.xml), how are you hitting the jsp? Are you forwarding from the servlet to the jsp? in that case, you have your own router logic in some servlet where you should handle the css, js and image files. If your logic in the router is correct, this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new folder under WebContent as css and add your css file
and then try the below code in jsp.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/yourfile.css" type="text/css" />
```

You can add firebug plugin in firefox and try to load the jsp file, which will help you in debugging,like whether the css file is loaded.Hope this helps.

Comment: Rather, just install chrome, it provides this functionality built-in at the developer tools! And i advise, always use chrome for development purpose. It's more better!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of ideas floating around, but I'd suggest bisecting the problem until a solution arrives.

1. Open the page with the external CSS. Look at the page source (from your browser or just save the resulting HTML somewhere). How does the link look? (Hint: It should be something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="…"/>`-
2. Open the CSS in the browser. Does the CSS load? If so, you've most likely made an error in the HTML-generating part of your HTML, but I think it is unlikely.
3. Look into your WAR file (perhaps with jar tf or rename it to .zip and look with some unzipper) – is the CSS included? Maybe it was discarded in your build process? Some builds reserve a `/resources/` folder for stuff like extra CSS files.
4. If the file is there, look at the tomcat logs, perhaps you will find an error there.

Answer (score 0):

Your css resource link may be wrong and you may need to provide a relative link from your *JSP* file. Try to link it as follows (note the use of the two periods to mention a one dir above your *JSP* file):

```html
<link href="../MyCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And as @dev already mentioned in his comment, `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyCss.css` as a path should already do the trick.

Comment: also rather than just using the two periods, try providing more periods and then specifying the absolute path, it's just a safety precaution. do like so    <link href="../../../../MyCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the file is not being served as a resource. You need to tell the server to expose a folder of resources to a certain path and move that file there. Since I'm not familiar with what you are using to setup your application (if you're using spring or something else), I can't give anymore insight on the problem.

Comment: Putting something inside WebContent folder automatically serves as resource

Comment: @dev: It depends on the container, the deployed war and the technological stack involved. Under certain conditions, that's true.